# Was bedeutet (von...aus)?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, grammatical-case

> **Von meiner Wohnung aus** kann ich das Rathaus und den Schlosspark sehen.

Was bedeuten *"von"* und *"aus"* in diesem Satz? Ist das ein grammatischer Modus?

Answer (score 2):

Das 'aus' ist optional.

Das 'von' gibt an, dass eine Ortsangabe folgt von der oder an der eine Handlung erfolgt, die woanders hin wirkt.

Vom Balkon (aus) kann ich die Brandung hören.

Von zuhause (aus) kann ich konzentrierter arbeiten.

Vom Flugzeug (aus) sieht am Boden alles wie Spielzeug aus.

Vom obersten Regalbrett (aus) fielen die Bücher zu Boden.

Vom Mailserver (aus) breitete sich der Trojaner aus.